# Using framer-motion to make sticky content animate out of screen and back in when scrolling up and down

Tags: reactjs, animation, css-animations, framer-motion

I have a problem nailing some feature using framer-motion. We have some sticky content, like a button which should animate out of the screen at the bottom when scrolling down (swiping up on phone), but come back in when scrolling down (swiping down on phone).

This feature is to give the user a better overview of the current page.

Tried to reproduce using code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/blue-wood-840toj?file=%2Fsrc%2FStickyContent.tsx%3A42%2C1

Really not sure if I'm doing it correct, but it just not feels smooth when scrolling up and down, sometimes the animation gets stuck? - and I guess it's because the state changes frequently.

It all works if i set the transition duration to 0, but then it does not animate :( so i guess it some kind of delay issue.